# Set icon on ActionBar using glide

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-glide

I am using glide to load image URLs in imageviews of recycler view and it works fine.

Now, I want to set ActionBar icon from a dynamic image URL.
How can I achieve it using glide?.

I have referred following link: [How to load a circular appcompat actionbar logo using glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845508/how-to-load-a-circular-appcompat-actionbar-logo-using-glide/38847248#38847248). 
But,I did not get the result. and I don't want to switch to picasso.

Can Anyone Help me?

My Code:

```
 Glide.with(this)
            .load(receiver1.profilepic)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.user)
            .into(new Target<GlideDrawable>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation)
                {

                    Bitmap bitmap1=((GlideBitmapDrawable) resource).getBitmap();

                    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap1);
                    actionBar.setIcon(drawable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(Drawable placeholder)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void getSize(SizeReadyCallback cb) {

                }


                @Override
                public void setRequest(com.bumptech.glide.request.Request request)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public com.bumptech.glide.request.Request getRequest()
                {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart()
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStop()
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroy()
                {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot of your ActionBar ? @Riddhi

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)`,
  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)` and then
  `getSupportActionBar().setIcon()`. You can also use a toolbar and customise it as you like.

Comment: Also, you can replace all that code with `new SimpleTarget<Drawable>` and setting `actionBar.setIcon(drawable)`

Comment: Thank you @Debdeep. Your solution worked for me. Please post is as answer so that i can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we set `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` and `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)` and then after managing the action bar icon visibility, just use `actionBar.setIcon(bitmap)` or `actionBar.setIcon(drawable)` to render the loaded image.

Comment: Using new SimpleTarget<Drawable> and then setting actionBar.setIcon(drawable) helped me. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing I would like to ask is how can we use actionBar.setIcon(bitmap) ? because as far as i know we can not set acttionBar icon directly as a bitmap. @DebDeep

Comment: Just like you did in the example

Comment: For such case, you may use `Glide.asBitmap()` and `new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you should enable two settings like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Then you can use `.asDrawable()` along with `CustomTarget<Drawable>()` like this:

```
Glide.with(this).asDrawable().load(imageUrl).into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
            getSupportActionBar().setLogo(resource);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

        }
    });
```

---

**Notes:**

- Make sure to replace the context (`this`) and `imageUrl` with your data.
- Don't use `SimpleTarget` as it is deprecated now starting from version 4.8.0.