# Glide does not display picture in a Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I just started to use Glide for loading images into my Android App. I use it within a Fragment and I would like to set the Background of a toolbar to a certain figure from an URL. Unfortunately glide does not show the picture but just a white background in the toolbar. The toolbar itself is not the problem as I can change its background with a color and this works. Also displaying a saved image from the App folder (I stored it in the drawable folder) works.

Here is my code which is executed inside the onCreateView method of a fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentGenericBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);




        ImageView image = new ImageView(getContext());

        image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Glide.with(this).load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614907301762-405163ba662f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80")
                .into(image);
        Bitmap bmap = image.getDrawingCache();
        binding.toolbarGenericMenu.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmap));

        //This code works at creates a green background
        //ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorGreen));
        //binding.toolbarGenericDrinkMenu.setBackground(colorDrawable);


       //This code also works and display an image from R.drawable on the toolbar
       // binding.toolbarGenericMenu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test_foto);




        return binding.getRoot();
    }
```

Any idea why loading the image with Glide does not work? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Provide the log and why new ImageView(getContext());?

Comment: You don't mention what kind of toolbar you are using, so check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515066/set-icon-on-actionbar-using-glide), specificly how .into() is used.

Comment: Thanks Eyosiyas for your comment. Well I have to somehow instantiate the ImageView. I tried also "ImageView image = null;" but it did npt work too. So I used "new ImageView(getContext());". What would you advice meto

Comment: Thanks javdromero for your comment. I use the androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if you are using `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` in layout in Kotlin

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.mToolbar)

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614907301762-405163ba662f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80")
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                        toolbar.background = BitmapDrawable(resources, resource)
                    }
                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
                })
```

Java

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mToolbar);
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614907301762-405163ba662f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80")
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        toolbar.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resource));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks Kishan for your answer. I use Java not Kotlin. Can you translate this in Java?

Comment: Any yes I use androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Updated answer for Java

Comment: Thanks Kishan for your answer. Now it workes as it should :-). I upvoted and accepted your answer. Maybe some follow up question:1) Can I always use the suggested code  from you whenenver I want to load an image via Glide. 2) Why do I need the method onLoadCleared and why is it empty 3) Do you know a good glide tutorial because on the one that I used the code did not work

Comment: 4) why do you use a Bitmap and not an ImageView 5)Do I always have to use the 'onResourceReady' and 'onLoadCleared' methods for every glide operation? Because on many tutorials I have not seem them at all. I'd appreciate any further comments from you.

Comment: 1. No, Generally when we use glide, we provide a view where it will render the downloaded images. So if you want some custom manipulation over the download image from the server or based on the downloading status we want some action, then use this approach.

2. When a load is canceled and its resources are freed then onLoadCleared callback called.

Comment: 3. https://www.raywenderlich.com/2945946-glide-tutorial-for-android-getting-started

Comment: 4. Generally we use imageview to render an image & pass that imageview reference to glide, so that glide can download & render the image into imageview. In your case ,you only want bitmap for toolbar. So we get bitmap from glide and passed to toolbar background.

5. No, in into() method you can directly pass image views reference. So if you want some custom manipulation over the download image from the server or based on the downloading status we want some action, then use this approach.

Comment: @VanessaF Please check answers for your other queries.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Kishan. I really appreciate your effort and your tremendous help. What I still do not really understand is when do I have to use your approach with the methods 'onResourceReady' and ''onLoadCleared'. In many tutorials (include the one that you gave me the link to) they do not use those methods and the code looks way less complex. Do I have to use it because I have a Bitmap and not an ImageView or ItemView? You write "if you want some custom manipulation over the download image"--> As far as I see it I do not do any manipulation. So why do I still have to use it

Comment: Do you also know a good tutorial about Glide where Java is used and not Koltin (I do not use Kotlin). I'd appreciate any further comments from you.

Comment: Thanks  Kishan Maurya for your comments and answers. I really appreciate it. Any comments on my last 2 comments? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Any comments on my last 2 comments?

Comment: Generally, we use glide for image rendering into image view. So we just pass image URL/drawable/URI to glide and image view reference. Rest thing like image downloading, image caching, image manipulation is handled by a glide itself. Normal usage

GlideApp.with(context)
    .load("http://via.placeholder.com/300.png")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
    .into(imageview);

So glide download image from server and render it on image view. But in your example  case , you want a bitmap from glide so that you can pass it to toolbar background.

Comment: Please read this article, you will understand
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

Comment: Thanks for your answers Kishan. I already knew the tutorial you gave me the link to but it does not really explain my case.

Comment: Generally I would like to thank you for your answer and your effort. I really appreciate it.